# Why do users upvote more on answers as questions?

Tags: discussion, voting

I saw with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841333/why-is-subtracting-these-two-times-in-1927-giving-a-strange-result/) there are only 2189 votes but with [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841333/why-is-subtracting-these-two-times-in-1927-giving-a-strange-result/6841479#6841479) there are 4441 votes.

The thing is without the the question there wouldn't have been an answer, so why are there more votes on the answer and not on the question?

Comment: Many people value more the effort of answering than of questioning.

Comment: It takes more effort to answer a question than ask it.

Comment: While self answers are a good thing; be especially careful to ensure it's not a duplicate

Comment: @juergend shouldn't that even itself out though, as question votes are worth half of an answer vote? Question askers are getting double-ended. They get half the votes for their questions, and the votes are each worth half.

Comment: @Cruncher It's an interesting question if thats true, probably the question gets half as much as the top rated answer, but probably not half the average answer (I'm thinking about all the 0 answers at the end of each question)

Comment: @RichardTingle the questions with a lot of 0's are usually the really popular questions. On the average question there's probably only a few answers often times all of which have more votes than the question. However, to me the bad answers are irrelevant. Just as bad questions are irrelevant. I want to compare good questions with good answers, which highest voted answer is a good metric of. (If it helps the argument at all, I'm primarily an answerer. Kind of like a woman against feminism)

Comment: @Cruncher In which case I'd say its fair that an averagely good answer is worth 4 times an averagely good question. Questions are important to, but nowhere near as difficult as answers

Comment: @Cruncher I approve of all people who argue against their own benefits!

Comment: That's strange, I tend to vote more on questions that answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- It takes more effort to answer than to question
- Answers have more information & usable data
- Answers are more helpful than the questions
- At times, users use the answers and don't even look at the question